# Removing values from list python, without square brackets

Tags: python, list, tuples

Does anyone know how I can remove some vaue from inside of tuple square brackets.

I have something like

```
def fun:
    val1=re.findall(pattern1, html_stuff)
    val2=re.findall(pattern2, html_stuff)
    return val1,val2

mylist=fun()
print mylist[0]
print mylist[1]
```

this will return

```
['stuff']
['more stuff']
```

I can't find out how to remove 'stuff' from []

---

I am building a new tuple with

```
new_tup.append((id,name, my_list[0],my_list[1]))
```

output looks like

```
('99', 'Event', ['5/03/2000'] ,['150'])
```

I want it to look like

```
('99', 'Event', '5/03/2000', '150')
```

or something that I can stick into sqlite with

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO events (id, name, date, cat) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', new_tup)
```

Comment: What? what is the final datastructure you want?

Comment: `re.findall()` returns a list of matches, if you only want a single match use `re.search()`.  This will give you a match object if a match was found, and you can use `.group(0)` on that match object to get the text from the match.

Comment: `fun` returns a tuple of two elements—`val1` and `val2`. So, `mylist[0]` is `val1`. Since `val1` is a list of matches, `mylist[0]` is a list. What did you _want_ to have?

Comment: Do you understand what those square brackets represent? `val1` and `val2` in `fun` are currently lists, so `fun` returns `(a_list, another_list)`

Comment: do you know how to not have it in list format, I just want the values themseves - val1 and val2

Comment: @amchugh89: The values themselves are lists. How could you have lists, but not in list format? What other format do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each findall returns a list, so your function returns a tuple of lists. You can solve the problem by indexing the list

```
mylist=fun()
new_tup.append((id,name, my_list[0][0],my_list[1][0]))
```

or by expanding the tuple when fun() returns

```
mylist1, mylist2 = fun()
new_tup.append((id,name, my_list1[0],my_list2[0]))
```